# mxgraph cell.getParent is not a function

Tags: javascript, mxgraph, jgraph

I am trying to implement the mxgraph. For non html value in the node or edge it's working fine but whereas for html value it's throwing the error cell.getParent is not a function.

Even I set the html options as
graph.setHtmlLabels(true);
graph.htmlLabels = true;

Below is the image with html value for node

[image]

Below is the image without html value node

[image]

Error at the browser console

[image]

Comment: I got the sample code from mxCodec.js file,,it's not parsing the xml content.

Answer (score 0):

Try change:

```
codec.decode(elm,model)
```

To

```
codec.decodeCell(elm)
```